# Google Map JavaScript API from server page: Directions Service: This API project is not authorized to use this API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I hava a problem about Google Map JavaScript API access.

I can access Google Maps API with Javascript class, Map, DirectionsService and Geocoder, from my local html file (C:\path\to\google.html).

Actually `MY_API_KEY` is valid key.

script tag is:

```
<script async defer type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initialize"></script>
```

but I can't use only DirectionsService with same source on localhost server(http://localhost:8080/static/path/to/google.html).

The console.log() message is:

```
Directions Service: This API project is not authorized to use this API.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

How can I access there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is: Directions Service: This API project is not authorized to use this API.

You need to authorize the Directions API in your API project